# Construction of a small but fat set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is it possible to find a subset $A$ of the real line $\mathbb R$ such that the Lebesgue measure of  $A$ minus its interior is positive ?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458974/does-the-frontier-of-an-open-set-have-measure-zero-in-mathbbrn) for an equivalent, more general question. Note that $\partial A = \overline A \setminus A^\circ$; the frontier is the set minus its interior.

Comment: @AlexR : Usually, $\partial A=\overline{A}\setminus A^°$, doesn't it ?

Comment: thanks. Still chosing a closed set you remain equivalent :)

Answer (score 1):

What about $(\Bbb R-\Bbb Q)\cap [0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

A fat Cantor set.  A is closed, its interior is empty, so $A$ minus its iterior is $A$ itself.  See previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/287872/442